# Why some pets seem to be afraid of black objects?

Tags: behavior, fear

I have noticed a somehow strange thing about several pets - they seem to be afraid of black objects, at least until get used to them:

- **Cat** - I have taken care of a friend's cat for about an year. Several times, she noticed a black purse and tried to touch it, but too afraid to get near it.
- **Dog** - My grandma adopted a dog, when already she had some cats. Not being raised together, they did not get along too well and all cats were scared of him, except of a completely black cat. This particular cat showed no aggressive behavior towards the dog, yet the dog was too scared to actually touch the cat.
- **Pigeon** - a rescued pigeon female entered our family some time ago. She mostly resides within a large balcony where have I also placed a black IP camera. By mistake she landed near it, but got really scared by it. After a while, she got used to it, as it clearly does not move and does not want to eat her.

**Question: are pets usually afraid of black objects?**

I think it might be connected to being afraid of darkness, but I could not find any information about this. Clearly, most of our pets see things differently (cats and dogs less colorful and pigeons can see more than we do), but nothing special about black objects.

Comment: I question the premise; I've seen no evidence of cats being more afraid of black objects than any other color.

Comment: Related [Do cucumbers spook cats? If so, why?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10834/do-cucumbers-spook-cats-if-so-why)

Comment: Interesting. I clicked on this thread because my cat is afraid of our wireless keyboard...it is black. Is it thing or just coincidence? I’m curious in how to solve this (apart from the obvious - get a white keyboard and see what happens) :)

Comment: My cat isnt afraid of black objects, but is afraid of anything that looks like a black snake, any black long or hanging objects.